# C golfing tips - returning 0 without return statement

Tags: code-golf, tips, c

I'm looking for some solution in returning values in main function, I need to shorten my program more, `return 0` takes too much characters of my code, I need to return 0, or my code fails. I know that in C there can be no `return` statement, and then program will use result of last operation - but on which operations I can 'really' shorten my code?
At the moment I found `brk(0)` as shortest return.

```c
main(n){while(~scanf("%i",&n))printf("%i ",n*~n/-2);brk(0);}
```

Comment: Which code-golfing contest requires that `main` return 0?

Comment: It would help to know some things: Can `n` be 0? Does extra whitespace invalidate the answer?

Comment: @feersum  it's from spoj challenges, code has to pass test - it has to return 0 or it does not pass it because of error, n can be <1,1001>, it can print answers with spaces, or new lines, it does not matter, judge checks numbers, i can even write 100x ' ' between each result

Comment: @encoree1337 "in C there can be no return statement, and then program will use result of last operation" - I think you are pushing it a bit there. Can you point to that being specified anywhere? As opposed to the result of last operation just coincidentally being left in the accumulator, which is where the return value would be on x86 (but not necessarily on other architectures)?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to do anything.

This assumption:

> then program will use result of last operation

is erroneous. If there is no `return` statement, `main` returns 0. It is *not* dependent on whatever might be left over in registers or anything like that.

From the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination**
>
> If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function **returns a value of 0.**  If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

(emphasis mine)

Your program's `main` already returns zero, or something is wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that the standard you are referring to is C99, not C89 (which is the default on most compilers), in which omitting the `return 0;` resulted in undefined behaviour.

So yes, **C99** and C++ allow you to omit the `return 0;` thing.

Comment: (and consequently, C11 too)

Comment: I believe the server in question indeed uses gcc in C89 mode, so this auto-return rule does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, the return value is generally dependent not on any previous "operation", but on the return value of the last function call. You are hoping that the function dumps a 0 into the EAX register, and that it stays there when `main` returns.

You may be able to get better mileage out of `atoi`/`atol` and `gets` here. When `gets` hits EOF without reading a line, it returns a null pointer. Then, `atol` will return 0 upon receiving a null pointer as input. Since 0 is not an allowed value for `n`, this can be used as the loop condition, as well as the way to drop 0 into the appropriate register.

```
main(n){while(n=atol(gets(??????)))printf("%i ",n*~n/-2);}
```

The only problem is to find some memory for `gets` to write on. I'm not familiar with the Unix-specific library functions such as `brk`, but surely you can find something 6 characters or less (needed for an overall shortening) which returns `char*` or `void*` among all the cruft.